# role of classic ASP theForm.NextAction.value and classic ASP projects (or lack thereof)

Tags: file, asp-classic, action

I have inherited a classic ASP set of files that is "Spaghetti" code [that's off my diet, but I digress].

There doesn't seem to be a project file that I can find.  Is that normal for classic ASP?

Also, what exactly does the following line do:

theForm.NextAction.value = "myAction1";

myAction1 seems missing in any search of the contents of the file-set (no project)!

Comment: Per tip of a colleague:  One can open the collection of files as a "web site", e.g. in VS 2011 one can use:   "File --> Open Web Site..."; this approximates what a project does, at least from a text searching perspective.  It also helped me find "myAction1"... still if anyone has any insight into what theForm.NextAction.value *does* I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Note:  Windows file search is somewhat suspect and doesn't always return all results one needs.  Also, it is actually worse than in the "paper clip" or "Rocky-the-dog" interface days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP applications do not require any centralized project or makefile. Each .ASP page is completely standalone with the only real exception being the use of any includes which would be referenced within the .ASP file itself. Like other scripting languages for web applications, classic ASP can interleave script code with HTML markup. And of course, HTML can include inline JavaScript code also. So a single .ASP file can potentially contain HTML markup, ASP scripting code, and client side JavaScript code. Any good text editor will easily allow you to search all .ASP files (and related HTML files) within a site to look for other references to your objects.

I mention all the above, as the code you reference really has no standalone context in classic ASP. Just from nomenclature, it likely just refers to elements defined on the page : a form element (NextAction) for the HTML form (theForm). Plus this looks more like it would be inline JavaScript code as most classic ASP was written in VBScript which does not use semi-colons. However it is possible to write classic ASP in JScript, it was not very commonly used.

Comment: Thanks!  It was really helpful.  As I mentioned above,  One can open the collection of files as a "web site", e.g. in VS 2011 one can use: "File --> Open Web Site..."; this approximates what a project does, at least from a text searching perspective.